# How to eliminate UV lines in render

Tags: rendering, uv

How can I eliminate the UV lines that show up as light reflection artifacts in my renders?  What am I doing wrong?

I have uploaded a zip file containing a minimal project (about 12 MB) that gives my output at https://www.randommonkeyworks.com/files/testRender.zip.

[image: Example of UV lines showing in crappy render]

Comment: no strange artifacts on render of your scene for me... both in Cycles and Eevee. Which are you using? Which Blender version? GPU or CPU rendering?

Comment: 2.82a. Cycles, Eevee, GPU, CPU, it doesn't make any difference. If you look closely at the render, you will see striations at the UV lines. Sorry I did not set the render up to present the effect, but if you go into 3d view and choose rendered mode, moving around the model will show the effect. Once you find an angle, if you lock the camera to it and then render, the effect will be obvious.  I have figured the problem out, so I will answer it below.

Comment: You're talking about UV lines in your subject,showing some weird artifacts that don't appear in the provided blend file (see here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnPLf.jpg)... and you're talking about baking parameters... Could you please clarify everything in your description and solution found because this is really not clear and that will help others a lot! Thanks

Comment: >> showing some weird artifacts that don't appear in the provided blend file << YOU APPEAR to have smooth-shaded the object (right-click on it and 'Shade smooth' option), and not to have re-linked the normals to the material. If those aren't done the artifacts I outlined in the post picture appear. If you have a place to post the zip file that accepts 12 MB, feel free to put do so and put a link to it. Otherwise I am going to remove it from my server in a while.

Comment: if you just attach a blend file without the clear instructions how to reproduce the issue, it will be difficult for anyone to help without spending or wasting a lot of time. Please edit your post description and add the details that will help the next viewer who faces the issue. Also, in order to attach a blend file to stackexchange questions, please use this: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting. This is a community Q&A site that's supposed to help everyone, not a one way technical support hotline.

Comment: _...not a one way technical support hotline._ As I posted an answer, obviously I did not treat this as such, so there was no need for a statement like that. Anybody who faces the same problem will now be able to google it and solve it with the existing text, since the problem is exactly what the title says. Thanks for trying to help, and have a great day!

Comment: You're right, may be a bit arsh, I apologize for that phrase. I stand by the rest. Also, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. When creating the normal map, make certain your objects are smooth shaded. I don't remember any of the tutorials I saw stressing the importance of this fact, but if they aren't smooth shaded Blender will not automatically interpolate to smooth, and your normals will have abrupt changes at the grid lines.